# How to set Default View for Party Lost in CRM 2016?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

The default view for a Party List field in CRM is the Account Lookup view and I want to change it to the Contact Lookup view. I used code that I found online and it had worked perfectly in the past, but after the latest CRM update the code stopped fulfilling it's purpose.Here is the code I was using:

```
function SetDefaultView() {
    var newViewGuid = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}";
    var layoutXML = "[valid layoutXml statement]";
    var fetchXML = "[valid fetchXml statement]";
    var ctrl = Xrm.Page.getControl("to");

    if (ctrl) {
        ctrl.addCustomView(newViewGuid, "contact", "Custom Contacts Lookup View", fetchXML, layoutXML, true);
        ctrl.setDefaultView("{a2d479c5-53e3-4c69-addd-802327e67a0d}");
    }
}
```

I omitted the complete `fetchXml` and `layoutXm`l statements here to save space. The GUID in the `.setDefaultView` method is a valid View GUID.

Is there a way to set the Default View for a Party List field in the latest version of CRM online now that this code is no longer functioning?

Answer (score 0):

The guid you pass as a parameter to `ctrl.setDefaultView()` must be a valid guid from a Contact view. You might be able to get one by using:

```
var contactViewId = Xrm.Page.getControl("to").getDefaultView();
```

If that doesn't return a Contact view guid, try just pasting one in manually.

Alternatively, add a [filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_addCustomFilter) to the `"to"` lookup before you call `getDefaultView()`.

Comment: The GUID I'm passing is a valid GUID. And there is a filter applied to the field that is working fine, once the user switches the view from Account to Contacts. The issue is that I want the view to be a Contact view by default and this is no longer working. It was working just fine before the latest CRM update.